# Read a binary file written by C in Go

Tags: go

What's the proper way to reading a binary file written by C?
I've a C header file, there are some 'struct's.
Is it possible to use these header file instead of manual re-write them in Go.

```
/* sample.h */
#define HEADER_SIZE 2048 //* large then sizeof(header)
typedef struct {
    uint8_t version;
    uint8_t endian;
    uint32_t createTime;
} header;

typedef struct {
    uint64_t data1;
    uint32_t data2;
    char name[128];
} record;
```

Here is my starting Go program with pseudo code

```
package "main"
// #include "sample.h"
import "C"
func main() {
  f, _ := os.Open("sample_file")
  // read(buf, HEADER_SIZE) and print out
  // use structure header to decode the buf
  // while not end of file {
  //    read(buf, sizeof(record) and print out
  // }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) can help.

Comment: @kichik: It appears from the question that the OP is already using cgo.

Answer (score 1):

Read them using the `encoding/binary` package that you can find at https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/

You can use `binary.Read` to read into a Go struct. You'll need to account for the padding the C version will add. In your example, default padding would put 2 pad bytes before `createTime`.